# "Required" attribute on model not respected when using Telerik MVC Extensions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, telerik-mvc

I'm using the Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC in an MVC3 project.

I'm finding that, even if I put the RequiredAttribute on my model property, the generated HTML doesn't have the appropriate extra attributes to support client-side validation.  Nor do other DataAnnotations attributes seem to be supported.

Am I right?  Are they just flat-out not supported?  I didn't see anything about it in Telerik's documentation.

If they are, what do I have to change/set/call to make them work?

If not:  short of completely re-writing the relevant extensions (there's a version that comes with source code), is there any known way to make the extensions work with MVC3 client-side validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking the Required attribute is supported by Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC. There are a few online demos showing that in action:

- http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/clientvalidation
- http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/clientvalidation
- http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/numerictextbox/clientvalidation

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am still having trouble getting client validation to work with the DatePicker and TimePicker, but have come up with a workaround.  Thanks again.